# Workflow not starting on adding new item to list via a custom aspx page/form?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-form, custom, custom-list

I am using FB Authentication and have a custom sign in page for Users(External) to request new accounts.

On request, their details are added to a custom list.

I have workflow on this custom list to email the administrator on a new item added.

The funny thing is, the workflow starts and completes when I add a user directly to the list by using the add new item link at the bottom of the list or the 'new Item' from the ribbon.

However it does not work when an item is added via the account request page

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow did not fire as the acount request/new item added to the list was carried out by the system account. Workflows do not fire automatically under system account.